# setInterval and clearInterval issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

```js
$("#down").click(function(){ 
  $("#move").animate({top:'+=75px'}, 160, 'linear')
  });
$("#up").click(function(){ 
  $("#move").animate({top:'-=75px'}, 160, 'linear')
  });
function game(){
    var a = [0,10,15,20,25,35,40,45,50,55,62];
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    var c = a[b];
    $("#box").animate({right: '+=100%'}, 1000, 'linear');
    $("#box").animate({right: '-=100%'}, 10);
    $("#box").animate({top: c+'%'}, 0);    
};

var timer;
$("#start").on('click', function(){timer = setInterval(game,1000)})
$("#stop").on('click', function(){clearInterval(timer)})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .move {
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px; top: 40%;
      height: 40px; width: 40px;
      background-color: rgb(0,255,100);      
    }
    .box {
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0%; top: 26%;
      height: 38%; width: 2.2%;
      background-color: red
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id = everything class = everything>
  <div class = move id = move></div>
  <div class = box id = box></div>
  <button id = start>Start</button>
  <button id = stop>Stop</button>
  <button id = down>DOWN</button>
  <button id = up>UP</button>
</div>
```

I'm having issues with this timer I'm using to build a simple game. The function I'm trying to loop is `function game()`, which makes the div "box", initialized at the far right of the screen, animate all the way to the left of the screen, then immediately back to the far right. Essentially, it creates the illusion of obstacles coming towards the player. Clicking button "start" sets the interval. Clicking "stop" should clear it.

If I want to set the period of the interval, I know I have to change the second value in `setInterval(game, x)`, but when I give a value x, only the first instance is delayed by that amount, then the function loops without delay. What is wrong with my function or the execution of setInterval? Do you have any suggestions for improving my method of accomplishing the above goal?

Also, my `clearInterval(timer)` only works sometimes, mostly when the period of the interval is long. Is there simply too much going on in the function and the program can't handle clearing the interval on a short period? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe event bubbling? You trigger every 1000 ms, but also inside game `$("#box").animate({right: '+=100%'}, 1000, 'linear');`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Markus Zeller. What do you mean by "also inside"?

Comment: can you please add html

Comment: See the quoted line of my last comment. The animation delays 1000 ms, too.

Comment: @chandukomati HTML added above.

Comment: **Note:** When game() is called from setInterval() and the method game takes longer than the next interval is planned, it won't be triggered until completed.

Comment: **Tip:** When you plan to use high frequent calls for game development, consider using [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: Thank you for the note; that makes sense to me. When I made the period longer than the length of the function, e.g 1200ms, the delay was consistent. I'll look into requestAnimationFrame(). Do you know what's causing the issues with the clearInterval? Is that also just lag in executing the fcn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `requestAnimationFrame` still find below answer for your issue

1) Use `$().finish()` to stop animation with smaller interval.

2) Also use `clearInterval(timer)` in your `start` as if you click start multiple times.

```js
$("#down").click(function(){ 
  $("#move").animate({top:'+=75px'}, 160, 'linear')
  });
$("#up").click(function(){ 
  $("#move").animate({top:'-=75px'}, 160, 'linear')
  });
function game(){
    var a = [0,10,15,20,25,35,40,45,50,55,62];
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    var c = a[b];
    $("#box").animate({right: '+=100%'}, 1000, 'linear');
    $("#box").animate({right: '-=100%'}, 10);
    $("#box").animate({top: c+'%'}, 0);    
};

var timer;
$("#start").on('click', function(){game();clearInterval(timer); timer = setInterval(game,1000)})
$("#stop").on('click', function(){
 $("#box").finish();
clearInterval(timer)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .move {
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px; top: 40%;
      height: 40px; width: 40px;
      background-color: rgb(0,255,100);      
    }
    .box {
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0%; top: 26%;
      height: 38%; width: 2.2%;
      background-color: red
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id = everything class = everything>
  <div class = move id = move></div>
  <div class = box id = box></div>
  <button id = start>Start</button>
  <button id = stop>Stop</button>
  <button id = down>DOWN</button>
  <button id = up>UP</button>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use ```$().stop()```you can stop the animation imediately

Comment: Thank you sir, your suggested setInterval method works perfectly! I incorporated yours and Zeller's feedback about requestAnimationFrame() in my script, which works a lot better than setInterval. Thanks for all your help!